# How do I get a vertical line to the left of the active menu item?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a vertical line to the left of the active menu item. I tried that by giving the active element a `border-left: 4px` and `padding-left: 50px;` have given. That didn't work the way I wanted it because the active link is no longer under all other links (see code). What do I have to do differently?

Is it also possible to change the height of the vertical line, when I use border-left?

[image]

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.side-menu {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #aaa;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  
.active {
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="side-menu">
   <div>LOGO</div>
   <div>
     <div class="active">Link 1</div>
     <div>Link 2</div>
     <div>Link 3</div>
     <div>Link 4</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: either `border-left` or `box-shadow` + `inset`. To change the height, simply add a fixed height or min-height.

Comment: As youcan see in my code border-left didn't worked.

Comment: it works perfectly fine as it is declared. easiestw ay would be to add a border by default and use as border color `transparent` then simply chaneg the border-color for the `.active` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same using pseudo class `:before` like below

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.side-menu {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.link-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.link-container>div {
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

.active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 4px solid #000;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="side-menu">
  <div>LOGO</div>
  <div class="link-container">
    <div class="active">Link 1</div>
    <div>Link 2</div>
    <div>Link 3</div>
    <div>Link 4</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: As you can see your solution works only, when the amount of letters of the links are the same. https://jsfiddle.net/jghqf3v6/

Answer (score 0):

What about making all the links behave the same way, that is keeping the 50px padding?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.side-menu {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #aaa;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
  }

.link{
  padding-left: 50px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
  
.active {
    border-color: #000;
 }
```

```html
<section class="side-menu">
   <div>LOGO</div>
   <div>
     <div class="link active">Link 1</div>
     <div class="link">Link 2</div>
     <div class="link">Link 3</div>
     <div class="link">Link 4</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This comes closer to my solution, but the links are shifted and no longer in the middle one below the other

Answer (score 0):

The border is taken care of just fine. The solution for your height related query, albeit not the best, is the only thing that comes to mind without changing too much of your preset configuration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  margin:0;
}
.side-menu {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #aaa;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.links {
    /*Must be equal to the increase in height.*/
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.links div{
    padding: 0 50px;
    border-left: 4px solid #00000000;
}

.active {
    border-left: 4px solid #000 !important;
    color: #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /*
    Set ( + npx) as per your liking
    (The percentage, 25 in this case,
    must be:- 100/(no. of links):
    */
    height: calc(25% + 10px)
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="side-menu">
     <div class = "logo">LOGO</div>
     <div class = "links">
       <div class="active">Link 1</div>
       <div>Link 2</div>
       <div>Link 3</div>
       <div>Link 4</div>
     </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```